# How to change the label of a filter in an interactive grid?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have a bunch of filters that I can apply in an interactive grid (Oracle apex). When they get applied they get labels automatically. Is there anyway I can change them manually? So, basically how to change the text of filters as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: My first thought is that this might be a bad idea, but let's see where it goes... Do you have an example of what you want them to say?

Comment: Some string it does not matter. "Lorem Ipsum" for instance.

Comment: Nevermind, you can change the heading of the column in application builder to achieve the desired result.